# Measure different between timestamps using conditions - python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to measure the difference between timestamps using certain conditions. Using below, for each unique `ID`, I'm hoping to subtract the `End Time` where `Item == A` and the `Start Time` where `Item == D`.

**So the timestamps are actually located on separate rows.**

At the moment my process is returning an error. I'm also hoping to drop the `.shift()` for something more robust as each unique `ID` will have different combinations. For ex, `A,B,C,D` - `A,B,D` - `A,D` etc.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [10,10,10,20,20,30],
               'Start Time': ['2019-08-02 09:00:00','2019-08-03 10:50:00','2019-08-05 16:00:00','2019-08-04 08:00:00','2019-08-04 15:30:00','2019-08-06 11:00:00'], 
               'End Time': ['2019-08-04 15:00:00','2019-08-04 16:00:00','2019-08-05 16:00:00','2019-08-04 14:00:00','2019-08-05 20:30:00','2019-08-07 10:00:00'], 
               'Item': ['A','B','D','A','D','A'],
                })

df['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])
df['End Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Time'])

df['diff'] = (df.groupby('ID')
                .apply(lambda x: x['End Time'].shift(1) - x['Start Time'].shift(1))
                .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Intended Output:

```
   ID          Start Time            End Time Item            diff
0  10 2019-08-02 09:00:00 2019-08-04 15:00:00    A             NaT
1  10 2019-08-03 10:50:00 2019-08-04 16:00:00    B             NaT
2  10 2019-08-05 16:00:00 2019-08-05 16:00:00    D 1 days 01:00:00
3  20 2019-08-04 08:00:00 2019-08-04 14:00:00    A             NaT
4  20 2019-08-04 15:30:00 2019-08-05 20:30:00    D 0 days 01:30:00
5  30 2019-08-06 11:00:00 2019-08-07 10:00:00    A             NaT
```

Comment: why not keeping the original timedelta objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df2 = df.set_index('ID')
df2.query('Item == "D"')['Start Time']-df2.query('Item == "A"')['End Time']
```

output:

```
ID
10   2 days 05:30:00
20   0 days 20:30:00
30               NaT
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

##### older answer

The issue is your `fillna`, you can't have strings in a timedelta column:

```
df['diff'] = (df.groupby('ID')
                .apply(lambda x: x['End Time'].shift(1) - x['Start Time'].shift(1))
                #.fillna('-')  # the issue is here
                .reset_index(drop=True))
```

output:

```
   ID          Start Time            End Time Item            diff
0  10 2019-08-02 09:00:00 2019-08-02 09:30:00    A             NaT
1  10 2019-08-03 10:50:00 2019-08-03 11:00:00    B 0 days 00:30:00
2  10 2019-08-04 15:00:00 2019-08-05 16:00:00    C 0 days 00:10:00
3  20 2019-08-04 08:00:00 2019-08-04 14:00:00    B             NaT
4  20 2019-08-05 10:30:00 2019-08-05 20:30:00    C 0 days 06:00:00
5  30 2019-08-06 11:00:00 2019-08-07 10:00:00    A             NaT
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think the time difference is correct

Comment: @jonboy you have not explained your logic. Here I only solved your error, not the logic ;)

Comment: `End Time` where `Item == B` and `Start Time` where `Item == C`. So they are located in different rows. I'm also hoping to use something more robust in case there are multiple rows between `B` and `C`.

Comment: can you check if the values in the update are what you want? You can then `merge` to the original dataframe

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use:

```
df1 = df.pivot('ID','Item')
print (df1)
              Start Time                                          \
Item                   A                   B                   D   
ID                                                                 
10   2019-08-02 09:00:00 2019-08-03 10:50:00 2019-08-04 15:00:00   
20   2019-08-04 08:00:00                 NaT 2019-08-05 10:30:00   
30   2019-08-06 11:00:00                 NaT                 NaT   

                End Time                                          
Item                   A                   B                   D  
ID                                                                
10   2019-08-02 09:30:00 2019-08-03 11:00:00 2019-08-05 16:00:00  
20   2019-08-04 14:00:00                 NaT 2019-08-05 20:30:00  
30   2019-08-07 10:00:00                 NaT                 NaT  

a = df1[('Start Time','D')].sub(df1[('End Time','A')])
print (a)
ID
10   2 days 05:30:00
20   0 days 20:30:00
30               NaT
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think the time difference is correct.

Comment: @jonboy - how is created `'16hrs'` ?

Comment: @jonboy - If need many combinations is possible reshape by `pivot`, then subtract MultiIndex Series.